# Specify list length as a goal in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to use the built-in predicate include/3 to get all lists in a list of lists that have a length greater than N.

I've tried this:

```
% S is the size I'm checking for
include((length(_, N), N = S), List1, List2).
```

but it didn't work. I'm unsure how to specify my length goal correctly. I'm particularly unsure of what put in place of the '_'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simpler way: provide a predicate with appropriate arguments (let's say, a *schema* adapter):

```
length_list(Len,List) :- length(List,Len).
```

and then

```
...,
include(length_list(S), List1, List2).
```

Depending on the system you're using, both [yall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=yall) and [lambda](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=lambda) libraries are good choices, worth to study.

Using yall:

```
?- L1=[[a],[a,b]],S=2,include({S}/[L]>>length(L,S),L1,R).
L1 = [[a], [a, b]],
S = 2,
R = [[a, b]].
```